# Can someone explain to me Dead Soul Jutsu

Tags: naruto

I watched episode 51 of Naruto (kid) and I noticed this jutsu. My question is how it works?

Comment: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Soul_Technique

Comment: Is there anything in particular about the jutsu that doesn't make sense to you that wasn't already covered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every part of the explanation I am about to give has been directly taken from the unofficial Naruto wiki : https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Soul_Technique

The Dead Soul Technique is described as a type of chakra-enhanced surgery. You can see it as an advanced puppetry technique which entirely forgoes chakra threads. Let's take it step by step :

1. **Kabuto performs open-heart surgery to induce a pulse.** Through unexplained means, Kabuto opens the thoracic cavity on a corpse. Then, he manages to jump-start the heart and create a continuous pulse. Maybe he's using a technological implement similar to a pacemaker ; perhaps does he use advanced chakra surgery techniques to recreate and maintain a pulse. Either way, the heart starts pumping blood again.
2. **Kabuto injects chakra within the corpse to control it from afar.** In essence, this is a forbidden, unethical puppetry technique which manipulates bodies from the inside. If I had to guess the exact inner workings of the technique, I would say Kabuto injects chakra within the victim's bloodstream, and manipulates that chakra to use the victim as a puppet. Either way, Kabuto needs to stay close to the puppet to keep manipulating it. He has also been shown to stay still while controlling the corpse ; and he can only control one at a time, meaning this particular puppetry technique demands high concentration.
3. **Kabuto stitches the body back up and performs additionnal surgery as needed.** Kabuto often performs cosmetic surgery to disguise the puppet. Likewise, he also suppresses its body odours through unknown means. Various chakra surgery techniques are most likely used during this process.